# how to make javascript style change last

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like this for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 class= "question1">How many letters are in "hello" ?</h2>
    <form class="answers">
        <input type="submit" name="answer1" value="1" class="answer" onclick="wrongAnswer(this.name)">
    </form>


  </body>

  <script src="JavaScript.js"> </script>

</html>
```

and this is the JavaScript.js

```
function wrongAnswer(name)
{
  document.getElementsByName(name)[0].style.backgroundColor  = "red";
}
```

when the button is pressed the background gets red but it doesn't last. It goes away in about 1 second. I want it to be changed as long as the page is not refreshed. How to do that ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: The `submit` is getting you a brand new incarnation of your page.

Comment: Just use a div or a button for your button, don't use input type submit

Comment: You can separate submit function from checking function.

Comment: @Dinesh thanks so much, I fixed the problem. I don't need form tag for the options but rather for clicking on "next Question" button.

Comment: @Merigold thanks, I might do that. Is it a better practise ?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. If my button is purely scripted front-end I usually use a div or button element and add my own behaviors in there. In your case yes it is better

Comment: @Merigold I see, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a submit button input. When it is pressed, the browser tries to send the form's data to a server and this reloads the page. You can use a button element instead:

```
<h2 class= "question1">How many letters are in "hello" ?</h2>
<button name="1" onclick="wrongAnswer(this.name)">1</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `form element` is triggering a `page refresh` on `submission` of it's contents.

This is normal.

Typical practice is to intercept said `form's` `onSubmit event` and `preventDefault()`.

See below for a practical example.

Note the `handleSubmit()` and `onSubmit` references in the respective `JavaScript` and `HTML` portions of the following code.

```js
// Handle Submit.
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault() // Prevent Default.
}

// Wrong Answer.
function wrongAnswer(name)
{
  document.getElementsByName(name)[0].style.backgroundColor  = "red";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 class= "question1">How many letters are in "hello" ?</h2>
    <form class="answers" onSubmit="return handleSubmit(event)">
        <input type="submit" name="answer1" value="1" class="answer" onclick="wrongAnswer(this.name)">
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="JavaScript.js"> </script>
</html>
```